# Eigenspace, Diagonalizable, Direct Sum

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $T$ is an element of $L(V)$. Prove that if $T$ is a diagonalizable operator, then $\mathrm{null}(T)$ and $\mathrm{range}(T)$ are direct sum of $V$.

Answer (score 5):

If $T$ is one-to-one, there is nothing to prove (and this is true regardless of whether $T$ is diagonalizable or not). Otherwise, $\mathrm{null}(T)$ is of dimension greater than 0. Every non-zero element of $\mathrm{null}(T)$ is an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $0$.

Let $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ be a basis of eigenvectors for $T$ with $Tv_i = \lambda_i v_i$ and order the $\lambda_i$ so that $\lambda_1 = \ldots = \lambda_k = 0$ and $\lambda_i \neq 0$ for $k < i \leq n$. Define $W_1 = \mathrm{span}(v_1, \ldots, v_k)$ and $W_2 = \mathrm{span}(v_{k+1}, \ldots, v_n)$. Then clearly $V = W_1 \oplus W_2$. Show that $W_1 = \mathrm{null}(T)$ and $W_2 = \mathrm{range}(T)$.

Answer (score 1):

- The case $\ker T=\{0\}$ is trivial: $V=\ker T\oplus\operatorname{im}T$
- Now assume that $\ker T\ne\{0\}$ so $0$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ with multiplicity  $m=\dim\ker T$. Now let $(e_1,\ldots,e_m)$ a basis of $\ker T$ so every $e_i$ is an eigenvector of $T$ and we complete this basis to a basis of eigenvectors $(e_1,\ldots,e_m,e_{m+1},\ldots,e_n)$ of $V$ then clearly $e_i,\; m+1\le i\le n$ lies in $\operatorname{im}T$ and by the rank nullity theorem we see that 
  $$\operatorname{span}(e_{m+1},\ldots,e_n)=\operatorname{im}T$$
  which allows us to conclude.

Answer (score 1):

Choose a basis of eigenvectors, which is possible since $T$ is diagonalisable. Order then such that the eigenvectors for eigenvalue$~0$ (if it is one) come before the others, and form the first $k$ basis vectors (so $k>0$ if and only if $0$ is an eigenvalue). On this basis $T$ is given by a diagonal matrix whose first $k$ diagonal entries are $0$, and the other diagonal entries are nonzero. Then one sees immediately that the kernel of$~T$ is the span of the first $k$ basis vectors, while the image of$~T$ is the span of the remaining basis vectors. Those subspaces clearly have a direct sum, equal to$~V$.